# Blender 2.81/2.80: How can I change the color of light of a spot - nodes seem to have no effect?

Tags: modeling

When changing the color field of emission shader node of a spot light in eevee it seems not to have any effect. This is valid in the node editor as in the light tab.
How can I change the color of light of light sources in eevee?

Comment: are you in sold mode or in rendered mode?

Answer (score 1):

Works the same for me in 2.8 & 2.81-
[image: screen grab]

So the answer is: in the light panel. Where my screen-grab shows the blue colour swatch, just under the type-of-light buttons.

I'm guessing you chose 'use nodes' for the light with Cycles as the renderer, if you notice my screen shot does not have the option in the light panel (as I'm using Eevee).
I had to chose 'use nodes' with cycles as the renderer before switching to eevee.
So the nodes should, by rights, disappear / become ghosted or whatever when you switch to eevee, but obviously do not... Somewhat annoying / confusing!

Help menu / report a bug (or a 'paper-cut' or whatever!)